# Is there something I can do to make Google index a brand new news magazine site faster?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

three weeks ago I launched an online magazine. Before the launch we had been working hard to make everything perfect.

So we have....

- unique base content
- valid sitemap, dynamically updated with every new article added
- properly set Google search console
- excellent page speed results
- many "starter" articles to start with full magazine

Immediately we launched the magazine we were indexed by Google and number of indexed page grows by hundreds instantly.

However, despite the fact we add fresh articles every day, Google indexes us once per three or four days. That is bad for us, because there are news our editors write as first ones in our country, but no one can find it on Google.

Should I just give Google some time, or is there something I can do to convince Google to index my magazine faster?

Comment: Not a lot you can do to change Google's timing.  However, have you looked at adding schema to your articles and marking them as "news".  See https://schema.org/NewsArticle

Answer (score 1):

If you have external links to your fresh articles it can help.

Also, please validate that you update the XML sitemap, and update google about the change every time

By the way, it can take time for Google to rank your website and index it more, 3 weeks is really fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use this website's that check your website graphics ranks?
Most of this websites will analytics your website and tell you how to improve your ranking in Google.

However you can't tell Google to speed in indexing your pages.
But remember the most things that Google are looking for is website that work good in mobile devices. Because most people use mobile devices today.